# iPhone: I can't change the color of my UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uinavigationbar

I can't change the color of my UINavigationBar.

I've put a navigation bar manually using Interface Builder, but I can't change its color to the following settings. I'm putting this code **on ViewDidLoad** (the code works fine with other classes on my app, except this one, where I'm using the UINavigationBar via IB):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.122 green:0.467 blue:0.255 alpha:1.00];
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check that you have the navigation bar connected through IB? as in, Did you declare a IBOutlet UINavigationBar in your controller, and then connected the navigation bar in IB to it's outlet?

Comment: Thanks! I totally forget to declare an IBOutlet.

Answer (score 2):

You might not be on the navigation controller stack at this point.  Trying putting it in viewWillAppear:

EDIT: You can check this by seeing if self.navigationController.navigationBar returns nil.

Comment: I tried in viewWillAppear, self.navigationController.navigationBar doesn't return nil but the color didn't change. What else could I try?